# How to troubleshot orchard

Tags: orchardcms

Just installed latest orchard 1.4.1 cms with sql se database. Have added new page with "Added to main menu" checked, but clicking on menu item shows "HTTP 404 page not found". How to find out what is wrong?

**Update**

I have found why. The page was published with title **'media'** and permalink **'media'** and looks like it is kind of special word in orchard routing. Changing permalink to **'new-post'** solved the issue it starts working properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found why. The page was published with title **'media'** and permalink **'media'** and looks like it is kind of special word in orchard routing. Changing permalink to **'new-post'** solved the issue and it starts working properly.

Answer (score 1):

First make suer, your permalink is automatically created or you write it manually. Then you should publish the page.

May be you done correctly but you saved the page only, not published!

Comment: Thanks for reply, yes I did publish that page.